# NSFetchRequest not catching objects that have a changed property

Tags: sql, macos, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have run into a weird problem with CoreData on MacOsX 10.6 using an SQL store. I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass called `Family` with attribute `name` and a relationship `personList` connected to another `NSManagedObject` subclass called `Person` with attribute `firstname` and inverse relationship `family`. A `Person` has only one `family`, and a `family` can have several `Person`s.

Say I have a `Family` object `family` pointing to the family 'Doe' with 2 `Person` (John and Jane) connected to it and I do the following request:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"family.name=%@",[family name]]];
NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

I get an array of size 2 with the 2 persons: Jane and John, with Family name Doe. Now, if I update the Family using its synthesized accessor, in my case:

```
[family setName:@"Wheat"]
```

I cannot after get the list of `Person` using the same fetch request. The results is an `[array count]` of `0`.

If I change the predicate to the following line, it works again:

```
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"family=%@",family]];
```

So it is as if the Predicate is not using the updated version of the property name of the family, even though I have the `NSFetchRequest` set to the defaults (so `includesPendingChanges` returns YES). That makes no sense to me. It seems that the `NSFetchRequest` finds the `family` object, but fails to see that its value `family.name` has been updated, not saved, and is in the `managedObjectContext` in memory. Of course, if I save the store, then it works again.

Any idea? I have been through the Mac documentation and cannot see why this would fail.

Answer (score 4):

I think the key here is understanding the fetch request. It retrieves data from the persistent store, so clearly, if you did not save to the persistent store, it will not find that data. The situation you describe is entirely logical if you take that into account.

From the Core Data Programming Guide:

> You cannot fetch using a predicate based on transient properties
>   (although you can use transient properties to filter in memory
>   yourself). Moreover, **there are some interactions between fetching and
>   the type of store**—for details, see “Store Types and Behaviors.” To
>   summarize, though, if you execute a fetch directly, **you should
>   typically not add Objective-C-based predicates** or sort descriptors to
>   the fetch request. Instead you should apply these to the results of
>   the fetch. If you use an array controller, you may need to subclass
>   NSArrayController so you can have it not pass the sort descriptors to
>   the persistent store and instead do the sorting after your data has
>   been fetched.

Comment: My property is not a transient property, it is a standard one, defined by 'property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name'; and 'dynamic name'. I did not checked the 'Transient' radio on the datamodel editor.<P>
I read the Apple documentation, and it clearly states that it can fetch objects that have been modified and not changed, that's why includesPendingChanges is set to TRUE by default.
I read the doc you cited (Fetching Managed Objects) but it's for he transient properties, not for the standard ones. In this same doc, there is an example above with NSPredicate. Makes sense?

Comment: I see what you mean. I do not think that the passage refers to transient properties, they are only mentioned at the beginning. The `NSFetchRequest` class reference is indeed very clear on this, and that must be confusing. -- However, could you check with `NSLog` what you get from `[family name]`? Perhaps you are not checking for @"Wheat"...

Comment: If I ask for [family name] I get 'Wheat'. That is the puzzling thing. The object family is up to date in the program, it's really the NSFetchRequest that does not see it.
I thought that you could do 'family.name=%@' in a NSPredicate for a NSFetchRequest. It's described everywhere on Apple Dev site. As I said, before, if I save the DB, then it works immediately. But it seems to contradict the idea that Apple does a clever job on Faulting etc... I am confused. Funny, if you don't have a '.' (so refer to a relationship), it works...

Comment: By this I mean:
[family setName="Wheat"];
then do a new NSFetchRequest on Family where the predicate is of the form: "name=%@", it works. But a predicate of the form 'family.name' for the Person fails...

Comment: Another note. On Apple, it says: "The SQL store, on the other hand, compiles the predicate and sort descriptors to SQL and evaluates the result in the database itself. This is done primarily for performance, but it means that evaluation happens in a non-Cocoa environment, and so sort descriptors (or predicates) that rely on Cocoa cannot work."   What does it really mean? That it only fetches items in the sql DB that is saved? But then, why is it working on the Family class (with a simple 'name=%@') and not on the Person class (with a 'family.name=%@')?

Comment: Actually, what does this sentence really mean: "To summarize, though, if you execute a fetch directly, you should typically not add Objective-C-based predicates" ?

Comment: I understand your confusion. Clearly, the dot notation is a bit tricky all over objective c;-). My recommendation is **not** to refrain from doing **saves**. They are very efficient if you do not do many hundreds or thousands in a short time. This should make life much easier and avoid such problems.

Comment: That was the only possibility I had left. Of course, this means that I would force a systematic save of my database, which is not necessarily a wise thing to do if you make a mistake.... But I may indeed have no other choice...

Comment: I think the "Objective-C-based predicates" are exactly the dot-notation ones.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize, I have been testing thoroughly my code and here is how I perceive the limitations of CoreData regarding Fetching and objective-c predicated (ie the dot notation).

> If an object has been access by the Objective-C program and if one of its property or relationship has been modified, any NSFetchRequest with a predicate using a dot notation will return the structure of the SQL store, hence the results will be erroneous.

In the case of the trivial **Family** and **Person** example, if you have a link to a **Family** and change its **name**, any query made on the **Person** NSEntity cannot include a predicate with the following query item

> @"family.name=%@"

It will indeed query using the family name in the SQL store. However, the following query will work after such a change:

> @"family=%@"

Indeed, the *NSFetchRequest* will still retrieve the info in the store, but since the structure has not changed, it will replace the objects retrieved by those in Memory, so a subsequent test to **[family name]** will return the updated name.

With care, you can use nested Predicate such as:

> @"person.family.name=%@"

As long as you can guarantee that all the objects that have the property **person**, have not their **family** altered, nor their **name** altered. If it's not the case, then you can at best call

> @"person.family=%@"

Or if you can't guarantee that all the **Family** objects are untouched, only

> @"person=%@"

Of course, an alternative is to systematically **SAVE:** the NSManagedObjects to the persistent store every time you make any change, so all properties are updated and then all the above notations would work. There are times however when you do want to prevent savings and force the customer to change it's document only if he wishes (think about Word, Excel, Picture tools, etc..). Hope this is of help.

Answer (score 0):

If by "using the same fetch request", you mean using the very same instance of the fetch request that you constructed the first time, then this is no surprise. The predicate you applied is "family.name = Doe". Once the family's name is "Wheat", the fetch request's predicate no longer matches it, because "Wheat" != "Doe".

To retrieve the family after changing its name, you would need to create a new instance of `NSFetchRequest` using a predicate matching the new family name.

If by "using the same fetch request", you mean using a different fetch request constructed using the same code, well, then I would think about @Mundi's answer.

Comment: I indeed did not mean the 'same' fetchrequest object but an new one with the same predicate look. I'll respond on @Mundi's indeed.