# iOS Core Data fetch newly inserted, not yet saved objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have to create some data in CoreData entities in batch (import process) and I would like to "commit" at the end or "rollback" on an error (so saving inbetween won't work).

The problem is that I for example need to create an entity "Person" and later in that progress I need to re-use that entity. BUT it can already exists BEFORE this process or may be created WHILE this import process.

So I'm trying to fetch it with a predicate "(personId == 4711)". But although I have set
`[fetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:YES];` it doesn't find the newly created Person object.

I read this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718737/core-data-fetch-request-and-unsaved-changes) and [this answer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html) which state, that it is not possible? Am I right?

If so, how can I workaround / handle this?

Comment: Don't know if it the case, if you have created the object in a different context than the one where the fetch is executed, than you cannot see the object, even if you have saved the context. You need to refresh the context first.

Comment: No, the object is created in the same context.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know of CoreData, this is indeen impossible (please correct me if I'm wrong).

However, even if this was possible, you never want to query your store on a "per object" basis.
The performance impact on large (more then a few dozens) imports is huge.

My suggestion for you is to create a dictionary keyed by your unique identifier during the import stage (prefetch from the store existing entities and create new ones for ones that aren't).

**Note:** You should be careful not to perform multiple inserts from different contexts in a multithreaded environment. in such cases you will need a coordinator to prevent duplications.

example:

store content: 1 --> P1, 3 --> P3
service response: 1 --> Data1, 2 --> Data2

Algorithm:
on response completion, get all unique ids from response --> `recievedIds` = @[1,2]
during the creation of `recievedIds` set create a mapping/dictionary of personId --> data:
@{1 : Data1, 2 : Data2}

fetch from the store by predicate:
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"personId IN %@",recievedIds]`
Create a dictionary from the resulting array.
in this case: `existingItems` = @{1 : P1}

Pass over all ids in `recievedIds`:
1) if the id exist in `existingItems` update the existing object
2) else create a new person and insert the data to the new record.

This will only fetch from the store once.
And you only save once.
==> only 2 trips to the store instead of a trip per object