# Update Core Data SQLite file

Tags: ios, file, sqlite, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I've created an app that works like this:

1. When the app starts the first time it reads a text file from my
   server. The text file contains thousands of tasks: "Task 1, Task 2,
   Task 3, [...], Task 1337".
2. Then it scans the text file and creates NSManagedObjects with attributes
   "name" (NSString) and "done" (BOOL, default NO) from the task strings in the
   text:

   ```
   NSManagedObject #1: name: @"Task 1", done: NO 
   NSManagedObject #2: name: @"Task 2", done: NO 
   NSManagedObject #3: name: @"Task 3", done: NO 
   ... 
   NSManagedObject #1337: name @"Task 1337", done NO
   ```
3. When the Core Data file is created the tasks are shown in a table
   view and the user can mark them as "done", so the done value of the
   selected NSManagedObject is set to YES.

How can I update the Core Data SQLite file when the text on my server changes and save the new tasks as NSManagedObjects?:

```
Example:
Old text file - "Task 1, Task 2, Task 3, [...], Task 1337"

New text file - "Task 1, Task 2, Task 3, [...], Task 1999"

(SQLite file contains task objects 1-1337 and should add tasks 1378-1999)
```

Or can you tell me better ways to save these tasks and update (delete/add/change) them?

Comment: try the algorithm described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869965/ios-core-data-fetch-newly-inserted-not-yet-saved-objects/18873917#18873917)

Comment: Your question is pretty simplified compared to the challenges you face when keeping data in sync between server and device. There are several questions you do not say anything about:
Can data be changed on server? Or just added to the end of the file?
What do you mean by "delete or change tasks"? Does that mean changing a task in the server file that may already have been downloaded to a device?